# Background Image portion with repeat-x

Tags: css

I have an image which is 99pixels wide and 100pixels height.

The image contains 3 vertical lines of colours Red, Orange, Green each being 33px by 100px in that image.

What I want to work out though is how to set the div background image to select lets say just orange and then repeat the image as the background.

So i did:

```
background-position: 66px 0px
```

The problem is the Green colour is still showing i only want it to show orange and repeat just that portion. Is that possible in CSS?

Comment: jsFiddle this sucker up.

Comment: Use `background-size`

Comment: Not possible.  You need a separate image.

Comment: @JoshC i believe that re-sizes it not selects a image portion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, not x-browser, unless you're attempting to repeat the background vertically for a div/box that is just 33px wide. If you really just want a colored background, just do e.g. `{background-color:orange;}`.

Comment: Yeah i can do it vertically but not horizontally. Surprised they have not added the support yet!  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Dave, you can do it horizontally but you'll need a background image with e.g. an orange section as wide as your container (but it needn't be as high, in that case you repeat-y to fill it vertically).

Comment: The idea was for a progress bar of which the width will change as it loads so i would have to have side by side elements :( think ill go for a simpler method!